# Plotting with data which occurs periodically

Tags: python, regex, awk, gnuplot

I have a data file:

```
######## Test at 123.45 start ########
######## File: abc.xyz ########
cores, pass_rate(actual), pass_rate(given)
1,7193,7210
2,10651,28840
4,10651,28840
8,10651,28840
######## End abc.xyz ########
######## File: def.xyz ########
cores, pass_rate(actual), pass_rate(given)
1,8619,8617
2,16567,16561
4,17256,66244
8,19874,66244
######## End def.xyz ########
```

I want to plot the data wherein the 2nd column ( i.e pass_rate(actual) ) for abc.xyz and def.xyz are selected and compare them comprehensively with the help of a plot.

With the help of cut and awk command I grabbed the data:

```
cat MYTEST_1.out | cut -d "," -f2 | awk '!/^#/'
```

which results in :

```
pass_rate(actual)
7193
10651
10651
10651
pass_rate(actual)
8619
16567
17256
19874
```

Unable to come across a script which grabs the data and graphs them i.e 1st pass_rate vs 2nd pass_rate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is the data concatenated? It would be easier to deal with if it were in separate files.

With some help from awk you can still use this format though. You can use the extraction technique I described [here](https://superuser.com/a/581381/133552), combined with Gnuplot. Note that Gnuplot will ignore lines starting with a number sign:

```
echo "
set key left
set datafile separator comma
plot for [i = 1:2] '< awk \"/^#{8} File:/ { f = 1; n++ } f && n == wanted; /^#{8} End/ { f = 0 }\" \
                    wanted='.i.' MYTEST_1.out' using 1:2 with lines title 'File '.i
" | gnuplot --persist
```

This will plot the first two sections of the file. Result:

[image: Plot of the first two sections of OPs input]

#### Edit - a more easily configurable alternative

*parse.awk*

```
BEGIN {
  print "set datafile separator comma"
  print "set key left box"
  plot_str = "plot"
  col1     = 1
  col2     = 2
}

# In the first pass we determine number plots, plot titles and x/y labels
FNR == NR && /^#{8} File:/ {
  plot_str = plot_str " '-' using " col1 ":" col2 " with lines title '" $3 "', "
  if(!xylabels) {
    oFS=FS; FS=" *, *"
    getline
    print "set xlabel '" $col1 "'"
    print "set ylabel '" $col2 "'" 
    xylabels = 1
    FS=oFS
  }
} 

# Skip rest of script if this is the first pass
FNR == NR { next }

# The second pass starts here

# Only print 'plot_str' once
!f { print plot_str; f=1}

# If line starts with a number assume it is data
/^[0-9]/

# Terminate plot sequence
/^#{8} End/ {
  print "e"
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile infile | gnuplot
```

[image: A better plot with proper keys and labels]

Or to plot the third column against the first one:

```
awk -f parse.awk col2=3 infile infile | gnuplot
```

[image: The same but plotting third column]

Comment: The way my script works is that it produces a cumulative output at the end with values for each of them. I was thinking of some mechanism to do the parsing. Also the actual output contains 4 ".xyz" files so had to call this function pin the main script. I guess.

Comment: @learning: you can parse it with the awk script I linked to in the answer. Not sure what you mean by *so had to call this function pin the main script*?

Comment: My main script ( in python) outputs the data in the form I mentioned in the question. I wanted to add the graph functionality along with the results and the format I mentioned above is the way I get those output. Say if i have the same sort of data ( not 2 times but N number of times), do I need to do : plot for i=[1:N] and what does wanted='.i.' do?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @learning: Yes you increase the for-loop counter. `wanted='.i.'` passes the for-loop iterator (`i`) into the awk script as the variable `wanted`.

Comment: @learning: It's an interesting problem, I've written a more elaborate and configurable awk/gnuplot alternative, see edit.

Comment: @learning: that's just what I called the input file, from your example that would be `MYTEST_1.out`. The file needs to be provided twice because of the two-pass solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is method with `python`:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p={}

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        if "File:" in line:
            key=line.split()[2]
            p[key]=[]
        if line[0].isdigit():
            x,y,z = line.strip().split(",")
            p[key].append([x,y])

for k,v in p.iteritems():    
    plt.plot(zip(*v)[0],zip(*v)[1],label=k)

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('cores')
plt.ylabel('pass rate (actual)')
plt.show()
```

Save it to `plot.py` and run like `python plot.py data`:

[image]

Comment: Thats a superb answer. I am running the same with matplotlib on my local machine but due to unavailable packages on my server side, I am much inclined to use bash.

Comment: Hi sudo_O: In case the out file has multiple .xyz data ( contrary to the one I have above where we have  only abc.xyz and def.xyz), in order to accommodate those data as well, I assume the tuple in plt.plot(zip(*v)[0],zip(*v)[1],label=k) needs to add extra elements. ?

Comment: @learning nope, nothing needs changing this parses the file for all `.xyz` files *(as long as the file names are different it will be okay)*. `p` is the dictionary where the key is filenames and the value is the coordinates so `plt.plot(zip(*v)[0],zip(*v)[1],label=k)` is plotting the x coords `zip(*v)[0]` against the y coords `zip(*v)[1]` and the `label=k` using the key (the filename) in the legend and that is for each entry in the dictionary `for k,v in p.iteritems():`.